# Maclaurin's inequality on elementary symmetric polynomials of arbitrary real numbers

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Is there a universal constant $C$ such that the following statement holds?  For concreteness, you may assume $C=10000$.

Let $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ be $n$ arbitrary real numbers.  For an integer $k$, let
$$S_k(a) := \sum_{1 \le i_1 < \cdots < i_k \le n} a_{i_1} a_{i_2} \cdots a_{i_k}$$
be the degree-$k$ elementary symmetric polynomial in $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.

Suppose $S_k(a)^2 \le \frac{\theta^k}{k!}$ and $S_{k+1}(a)^2 \le \frac{\theta^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ for some $\theta > 0$ and integer $k$.  Then
$$ S_t(a)^2 \le \frac{(C \theta)^t}{t!}$$
for every $t \ge k$?

What if $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \{-1,1\}$?

When the $a_i$'s are nonegative, this is true because of Maclaurin's inequality.  I am interested in the case where the $a_i$'s are arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: What is $C$ allowed to depend on? The way you formulated the question, it seems like $C$ could depend on $a$, $k$ and $\theta$. But this would be trivial, since $S_t(a)$ is zero for $t$ sufficiently large, so you can certainly choose $C$ so that the finitely many nontrivial inequalities $S_t(a)^2 \le \frac{(C \theta)^t}{t!}$ hold.

Comment: $C$ is a universal constant, independent of any of the given parameters.  For concreteness, you can take $C$ to be 10000.

Comment: By continuity you can make $S_k=S_{k+1}=0$ while $S_{k+2}$ is non-zero, and then taking $\theta$ sufficiently small shows no such $C$ can exist.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky I am not sure I follow.  In fact, if $S_k = S_{k+1} = 0$ then one can show that $S_t = 0$ for every $t \ge k$.

Comment: @nichehole I might be wrong; could you share your proof of this fact ($S_k=S_{k+1}=0 \implies S_{k+2}=S_{k+3}=\ldots = 0$)? (My intuition is that if you fix $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-3}$ then I expect the system $S_{k}=S_{k+1}=0$ to have plenty of solutions $(a_{n-2},a_{n-1},a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and generically $S_{k+2}$ will not be 0 for them. But I haven't formalized this.)

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky  Please see Appendix A in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3543.pdf#page=26

Comment: @nichehole Thanks!

Comment: For $t=k+2$ your desired inequality means $|S_{k+2}(a)|^{1/(k+2)} \le C (|S_{k}(a)|^{1/k} + |S_{k+1}(a)|^{1/(k+1)})$. Do you know how to prove this special case?

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky I do not, even assuming $a$ has exactly $w$ many $1$'s and $n-w$ many $-1$'s.  The problem becomes understanding the coefficients of $(1+x)^w (1-w)^{n-w}$.  This is related to Krawtchouk polynomials.

Comment: A similar bound to what you seek is claimed (but not proven) as Theorem 2.1 of this paper of Doron, Hatami, and Hoza as a consequence of the results of Gopalan and Yehudayoff that you cite: https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/149/. In full disclosure, it's not entirely obvious to me how to deduce this as the scaling seems to go awry in my back-of-the-envelope calculations, but I didn't try too hard to figure it out...

Comment: Erm... Maclaurin's inequality would give the desired result *without* the square on the LHS. Are you sure you didn't mean the absolute value instead of the square?

Comment: @fedja The statement is not true if we replace the square with absolute value.  If we consider $a$ containing equal number of $1$'s and $-1$'s, then $|S_k(a)| = \binom{n/2}{k/2}$ for even $k$ and $0$ for odd $k$.

Comment: Ah, OK. So it is a bit weaker than Maclaurin. Interesting :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've just completed a short paper establishing a positive answer to this question [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05328) (see also [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2023/10/10/a-maclaurin-type-inequality/)).  In terms of the elementary symmetric means
$$ s_k(a) := \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} S_k(a)$$
the estimate is established in the equivalent form
$$ |s_t(a)|^{1/t} \ll \frac{t^{1/2}}{k^{1/2}} \max( |s_k(a)|^{1/k}, |s_{k+1}(a)|^{1/(k+1)}) \tag{1}$$
for any $1 \leq k \leq t \leq n$.  The bound here is optimal up to constants; by contrast, the method of Gopolan and Yehudayoff mentioned in comments can yield the weaker bound
$$ |s_t(a)|^{1/t} \ll t^{1/2} \max( |s_k(a)|^{1/k}, |s_{k+1}(a)|^{1/(k+1)})$$
but I was not able to extend that method to obtain the optimal bound.

The proof of (1) is elementary, and not too long (the paper is 11 pages), but still not short enough to fit into a single MO answer.  I will however note a key step in the argument is to establish the preliminary inequality
$$ \sum_{m=0}^t \binom{t}{m} |s_m(a)| r^{t-m} \geq ( |s_t(a)|^{2/t} + r^2)^{t/2} \tag{2} $$
for all $1 \leq t \leq n$ and $r>0$.  To illustrate the proof of this inequality let us consider the model case $t=n$ and $|s_n(a)|=1$, so that the claim is now
$$ \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} |s_m(a)| r^{n-m} \geq ( 1 + r^2)^{n/2}.$$
If one evaluates the polynomial
$$ P(z) = \prod_{j=1}^k (z-a_j) = \sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} s_m(a) z^{n-m}$$
at $z=ir$ and uses the triangle inequality, one obtains (after taking logarithms)
$$ \log (\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} |s_m(a)| r^{n-m}) \geq
\sum_{j=1}^k \log |ir - a_j|.$$
However, a simple application of convexity reveals the inequality
$$ \log |ir-a_j| \geq \frac{1}{2} \log(1+r^2) + \frac{1}{1+r^2} \log |a_j|;$$
since $\sum_{j=1}^m \log |a_j| = \log |s_n(a)| = 0$, the claim then quickly follows.

Morally speaking, the claim (1) will follow from (2) by setting $r \asymp (k/t)^{-1/2} |s_t(a)|^{1/t}$ and neglecting all but the $m=k,k+1$ terms from the left-hand side, although showing that these terms can in fact be rigorously neglected in a key special case is what takes up the majority of the proof to justify.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks, Terry! I just finished reading the paper. While still digesting it, I want to point out that there seems to be a series of minor typos right after Eq.(4.4), making it a bit difficult to follow. In particular, I think the last displayed equation in p.8 is not correct. 
 (For a sanity check, if $k$ is large then the quantity on the right hand side is also large. I think the substitution, that you want to replace $\ell-k'$ in Eq.(4.2) with $k'$, is done incorrectly.)  Also, right before Eq.(4.7), $\frac{m(m-k')}{n-k'}$ should be $\le 0$ rather than $\ge 0$, because $m \le k'$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make the changes.  If you can send me your name (e.g., to my email at tao@math.ucla.edu) I can acknowledge you in the next revision of the ms.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
A = \max_i|a_i|,
$$
then we have that
$$
|S_{k}(a)| \leq \binom{n}{k}A^k .
$$
In particular, we have that
$$
\theta_k := \sqrt[k/2]{\frac{n!A^k}{(n-k)!}}
$$
gives us the sharpest bound
$$
S_{k}(a)^2 \leq \frac{\theta_k^k}{k!}
$$
since I can make $a_i = a_j$ for all $i,j$ to make this an equality.

However, note that
$$
\theta_1 > ... > \theta_n,
$$
since
$$
 \frac{\theta_k}{\theta_{k-1}} = \frac{\sqrt[k/2]{\frac{n!A^k}{(n-k)!}}}{\sqrt[(k-1)/2]{\frac{n!A^{k-1}}{(n-k+1)!}}} = \frac{\sqrt[k/2]{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}}{\sqrt[(k-1)/2]{\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!}}} = \frac{n^{2/k}\cdot...\cdot (n-k+2)^{2/k} }{n^{2/(k-1)}\cdot...\cdot (n-k+2)^{2/k-1}}\cdot (n-k+1)^{2/k}.
$$
Since $0<x<1 \iff 0<x^2<1 $ we can simply prove
$$
n^{-1/[k(k-1)]}\cdot...\cdot (n-k+2)^{-1/[k(k-1)]} \cdot (n-k+1)^{1/k}<1
$$
which is true.

If $a_i = a_j$, then $\theta \geq \theta_{1}$ and
$
C = 1 
$
works.

> Furthermore, a similar argument gives us that this works if
> $$S_1(a)^2\geq (S_2(a)^2 2!)^{1/2}  \geq ... \geq (S_n(a)^2n!)^{1/n},$$
> since we must have that
> $$
> \theta \geq (S_k(a)^2 k!)^{1/k} \geq ...
> $$
> for some $k$.

If we add the restriction
$$
a \in [-1,1]^n,
$$
then yes, it also works; since $S_k(a)$ now becomes bounded (above and below) for each $k$ and the question becomes trivial since the continuous image of a compact set is bounded (see [1]) and we can bound the biggest possible jump between $S_k(a)$ by using the min and max.

A necessary condition for $C=1$ to not work is that
$S_1(a)^2< (S_2(a)^2 2!)^{1/2}  < ... < (S_n(a)^2n!)^{1/n}.$ Can this happen?

[1]
*Munkres, James R.*, [**Topology.**](https://oeis.org/A122835), Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall. xvi, 537 p. (2000). [ZBL0951.54001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0951.54001).

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a mistake in your counterexample.  The $\theta_k$ does not seem correct.  In fact, when the $a_i$'s are nonnegative, the statement is true because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality.  Specifically, it says that $(S_{t}(a)/\binom{n}{t})^{1/t} \le (S_k(a)/\binom{n}{k})^{1/k}$ for every $t \ge k$, from which it is not hard to verify the statement.

As for your proof sketch, it seems that your constant $C$ can depend on $k$? 
 The statement is asking whether $C$ can be a universal constant that is independent of everything else.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the mistake. I changed the $A$ to $A^k$. Is that the mistake you were talking about? Also for the other issue, since $\theta_1 < ...< \theta_n$, you can take $C = \theta_n/\theta_1$ and then $\theta$ does not depend on $k$. Does this resolve that issue as well?

Comment: If we solve $S_k(a)^2 := \binom{n}{k}^2 A^2 = \theta_k^k/k!$ for $\theta_k$, then we get $\theta_k = ((n!/(n-k)!)^2 k! A^2 )^{1/k}$ instead of what you wrote in the 3rd displayed eq.

Comment: I also don't follow why it must be the case that $\theta_1 < \cdots < \theta_n$.

Comment: Ah crap, I must have confused myself with the $\sqrt[x/z]{y}$  notation (since my brain switched $x$ with $z$ lol). Looks like it actually goes the other way $\theta_1 > ... > \theta_n$. I will try to fix it now and if I can't fix it soon I will retract the first part of the answer. However the second part of the answer looks correct to me (i.e., $a_i \in [-1,1]$).